# Writing a set using intersections and unions

Tags: measure-theory

I want to write sets of the form
$\{x \in X : \text{some condition}\}$ as a union and intersection of sets.

For example one can write the set where a sequence of functions does not converge pointwise as
$\{x \in X : \exists \epsilon>0 \forall N \exists n\geq N : |f_n(x)-f(x)|>\epsilon \}$.

I would like to write this in the form of unions and intersections.
I found an awnser here :[Proving pointwise convergence almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2944937/proving-pointwise-convergence-almost-everywhere)

But I dont understand why the exist quantor of some condition translates to the union over this condition. And the same for the allquantor and the intersection.

I thought that maybe its in the definition of the for example union. But as far as I know $A \cup B =\{x: x \in A \text { or } x \in B\}$. But there is no quantor. Could maybe someone explain to me why $\exists$ translates to union and $\forall$ translates to intersection.

Comment: $\exists$ is somewhat similar to an infinitary “or” - to say $x$ satisfies that there exists $y$ with some property $p(x, y)$ is the same as an infinitary “or” ranging over all possible $y$ - if, say, the possible values of $y$ can enumerated by $y_0, y_1, \cdots$, then there exists $y$ with $p(x, y)$ is the same as $p(x, y_0) \vee p(x, y_1) \vee \cdots$. Similarly, $\forall$ can also be understood as akin to an infinitary “and”.

Comment: One can make the above more formal and precise, but that is the basic idea.

Comment: Intuitively, $\forall$ is a (possible infinite) conjunction and $\exists$ similarly a disjunction.

Comment: For all N can be interpreted as "For N=1, AND N=2, AND N=3, AND N=4, ...", thus an intersection. Conversely, there exists an n can be interpreted as "Either n=1, OR n=2, OR n=3, OR n=4, ..." thus a union. This was just to include a more "semantical" answer to the comments above.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** It's definition. The intuition behind it is described in the comments.

Let $O$ be a set and consider a family of subsets $X_i\subset O$ for every $i\in I$, where $I$ is any set. Then by definition
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=\{x\in O\,\vert\, \exists i\in I:x\in X_i\}, \quad\bigcap_{i\in I} = \{x\in O \,\vert\,\forall i\in I:x\in X_i\}.
$$

---

**Add-On:**
When the sets $X_i$ are given by some condition $A_i$ (that is, $A_i(x)$ is a statement for every $x\in O$ which is either true or false) by
$$
X_i=\{x\in O\vert A_i(x)\text{ is true}\}
$$
then
$$
\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i=\{x\in O\,\vert\, \exists i\in I:A_i(x)\text{ is true}\}, \quad\bigcap_{i\in I} = \{x\in O \,\vert\,\forall i\in I:A_i(x)\text{ is true}\}.
$$

Now let's apply this to your example. Say $f_n$ and $f$ are defined. Then for $\epsilon >0$ consider the set
$$
X_\epsilon =\{x\in\mathbb R\,\vert\,\forall N\in \mathbb N: \exists n\geq N: \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert < \epsilon\}.
$$
Now your set
$$
S=\{x\in \mathbb R\vert \exists \epsilon >0:\forall N\in \mathbb N: \exists n\geq N: \vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert < \epsilon\}
$$
can be written as
$$
S=\{x\in \mathbb R\vert \exists \epsilon >0:x\in X_\epsilon\}=\bigcup_{\epsilon>0} X_\epsilon.
$$
Iterating this idea you get
$$
S=\bigcup_{\epsilon>0} \bigcap_{N\in \mathbb N} \bigcup_{n\geq N} X_{\epsilon,n},\quad\quad X_{\epsilon,n} = \{x\in\mathbb R\vert\,\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert < \epsilon\}.
$$